# Selecting multiple columns with the same name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to access two tables in mysql and want to use the fields in both tables. I used a innerjoin to match both tables, but wondering how to fetch the field in both tables, coz both tables are having same field name and different values.
Here is my query...

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT facilitator.FacID, facilitator.email, assigned.email FROM facilitator INNER JOIN assigned ON facilitator.FacID = assigned.FacID WHERE assigned.email = '$stuemail' AND facilitator.active = '1'") or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
            while($line1=mysql_fetch_array($query1,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                $faci= $line1['FacID'];
                $facemail = $line1['email'];
                $stumail2 = $line1['email'];
.............code goes on..............
```

I want to fetch both emails field values but wondering how to do. I am sure what I have wrote for $stumail2 is wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options.

The first would be to assign a field-alias in MySQL:

```
SELECT
    facilitator.FacID,
    facilitator.email AS facilitatorEmail,
    assigned.email AS assignedEmail
    ....
```

The second, since you're using `mysql_fetch_array()`, is to access the fields by their index. The `facilitator.email` field has index `1` and `assigned.email` has index `2`, so you could use:

```
$facemail = $line1[1];
$stumail2 = $line1[2];
```

Alternatively, by default, MySQL *should* be adding an incremental number (starting at `1`) for each duplicate column name. So, you should be able to use `email1` to access the `assigned.email` column:

```
$facemail = $line1['email'];
$stumail2 = $line1['email1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases on the columns to disambiguate them, e.g.:

```
SELECT facilitator.FacID, 
    facilitator.email as FacilitatorEmail, 
    assigned.email as AssignedEmail
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need the 'as' keyword in your query:

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT facilitator.FacID, facilitator.email as fac_email, assigned.email as assign_email FROM facilitator INNER JOIN assigned ON facilitator.FacID = assigned.FacID WHERE assigned.email = '$stuemail' AND facilitator.active = '1'") or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        while($line1=mysql_fetch_array($query1,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $faci= $line1['FacID'];
            $facemail = $line1['fac_email'];
            $stumail2 = $line1['assign_email'];
```